# Object Creation Logic in Java

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to understand the memory management scheme for JVM

Consider two classes A, B

```
Class A {

public A() {
//Do Something
}

}

Class B() extends A{

public B(){
super();
// DO something again
}
}
```

From main 
    B b = new B();

As per my knowledge the Class loader will load A, B and will create 2 objects each. Is there any other object that would get created?

Also the second part of my question is that , while accessing Java Visual VM , I see objects of Java NIO package has been created. Is there any way I can prevent JVM from creating objects which are not related to my project?

Comment: JVM create objects for its internal process also so you cant predict the actual no. of objects created by JVM.

Comment: i think question is answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220133/java-instantiation]

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is that there will be only one object created. Basically, for every "new" statement, there is one object created. So I think your assessment about two objects being created is wrong.

Secondly, I do not think you have any control on the JVM with respect to the objects that are created (not related to your project).

Lastly, for a more detailed answer to the first part of your question you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877615/how-many-objects-are-created-due-to-inheritance-in-java)