# Object creation on Heap

Tags: java, heap-memory

```
class Person {
    public Person(){}
}
class Employee extends Person{
    public Employee() {}
}
class Manager extends Employee{
    public Manager() {}
}
public class HeapObjectTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Manager manager = new Manager();}
}
```

How many object will create on the Heap for Above code?

Comment: The JVM will create around 10,000 objects just getting to the main() method, one more isn't going to make much difference.  Note: loading a class for the first time creates lots of objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object Creation Logic in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115207/object-creation-logic-in-java)

Comment: This is a homework question, right? You should forget about the heap, that's a complete red herring. Just think about how inheritance works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we talk about only your code, then there is only `one Manager object`, and there will be constructor-chaining till Object class. Apart from this object there will be other objects also which are needed by JVM to run your program, these will be `class objects, method objects` which are currently loaded in to run your program.

For more details about the execution order of any program, to get more understanding, please read once below link,

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Invoking this line of code:

```
Manager manager = new Manager();
```

Will create one **object**, an instance of the `Manager` **class**. The implementation of the `Manager` class borrows from the implementation of the `Employee` and `Person` classes - however, just because you inherit from those classes, doesn't mean that they get treated as separate objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your program will create only one Object for Manager class. Manager class extends the properties/behavior of Employee and Person but it will create object for only Manager and not for others.

As per basic definition of Object- it is an instance of the class and class is just a blue print on how the object should be created. Hope this helps.